# Running/Debugging ServiceMix application with Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-servicemix

I have been trying to find some documention on whether it's possible to run ServiceMix with IntelliJ for running/debugging purposes?

Does anyone know how to do this/point me to some kind of guide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm debugging servicemix app with remtoe debugging. 
Run server with "debug" parameter ($SERVICEMIX_HOME/bin/servicemix debug) and connect to it with Remote Run/Debug configuration in Idea.
Servicemix starts debug on default 5005 port so simply change the SM server host name in Idea configuration.